# Volley string request returns random character

Tags: java, android, httprequest, android-volley

I'm new to HTTP requests.
In my app I want to send a simple GET request from my API, which I first test in an API tester, and the response looks like this.
[image]

and for now I want to print out the exact same response with my app, so I use a `StringRequest` from the Android Volley Library. Here's my code.

```java
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, TEST_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.println(Log.INFO, "SONGTUBEAPI", response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.println(Log.ERROR, "SONGTUBEAPI", error.toString());
                    }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

but now my response contains random characters.

> 2019-10-07 17:59:34.929 5140-5140/com.steven_wang.audioplayer I/SONGTUBEAPI: ������ftypdash��������iso6mp41����xmoov������lmvhd��������ØóíÜØóíÜ����¬D��¯������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������@������������������������������������������������������������������(mvex������ trex������������������������������������������������Ütrak������\tkhd������ØóíÜØóíÜ����������������¯��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������@��������������������������xmdia������ mdhd��������ØóíÜØóíÜ����¬D��¯��Ç����������*hdlr����������������soun������������������������ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 05/04/2019.��������ñminf������$dinf������dref��������������������url ������������µstbl������istsd��������������������Ymp4a������������������������������������������¬D����������5esds��������'����@��������������������������������������������������������stts����������������������stsc����������������������stco����������������������stsz������������������������������smhd��������������������dsidx������������������¬D������������������������xä��¸����������w&��¸����������w'��¸����������vä��¸����������wl��¸����������vÕ��¸����������wZ��¸����������w!��¸����������w!��¸����������wG��¸����������w,��¸����������w:��¸����������w3��¸����������wA��¸����������v°��¸����������w¤��¸����������vð��¸����������w��¸����������wR��¸����������væ��¸����������w¦��¸����������v��¸����������wó��¸����������wm��¸����������v��¸����������vó��¸������������æ����T������������moof������mfhd��������������������traf������tfhd����*��������������������������������tfdt��������������������Ìtrun��������®���� ����s����t������������­����é����Ò����Ú����¹������������a����Q����`����[����i��������|����������������v����²����;����p����2����H����J����P����e����c��������i����s����n��������Í����`����{����j����*����Y����X����U����f������������s����n����s��������H����8����R����P����Q����*����g����h����Ú����*����V����j������������¼����^����j����p����E����F����b����X����`����ø����©������������Y����¢����T����N����a����H����Y����^����g����`��������f����s����e��������­����j����u��������V����p����b��������c������������u����W����|����h����¼����C����N����N����V����R����h����h����^��������b����h����j������������z����j����Y����Y����m����*����g����c����É����ª��������j��������l����}����J����G����N����U����X����]����`����a������������v����r����´����Ì����`����j����a����e����*����d����h����Z��������¦����c����i����Y��������M����F����p����Z����Q����c����a����q��������k����l����v����{��������¸����l����p����X����X����U����e����g����^����ó����È����l��������}����©����9����R����w����X����W����`����S����h��������l����c����x��������à��������e����p����<����c����e����}����P������������`����*����r����U����r����I����Y����B����Y����h����`����g����o����¬����f����s������������©����d����v����v����H����J����a����[����e����ö������������a����Y����}����X����S����P����V����n����f����\����v����Ï����c����w����h����k����©����³����B����m����H����\����h����f����k����o����î��������~��������N����¼����H����b����k����Y����a����_����W����b����Æ����l����j����W����l��������±����c����o����I����M����^����i����h����Ä����±����N����p��������c����­����C����p����T����_����]����`����s����q����¡����b����{����d����{����Ð����\����l����d����Z����Z����c����\����k��������Ë����t����j����{��������Y����=����g����E����Z����S����`����*����¯����[����V����h����s��������Ë����k����R���

What am I doing wrong? I tried fixing the encoding to utf-8 but the result is still the same.

Comment: That looks like binary data. And since you use songtube, this might be binary audio data. The few printable words (ISO Media file, mp4) seem to confim this. So Volley might follow the redirect (which is mentioned in the api tester response) and give you the audio resource.

Comment: @f1sh is there a way to disable the redirect? Thanks!